# Audio recorded with Ubuntu 23.04 is strangely distorted/warped

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

### **Problem: Audio Distortion**

When I record audio from my [Logitech H111 wired headset](https://www.amazon.ca/Logitech-Headphones-Noise-Cancelling-Microphone-Smartphone/dp/B00YJJB7YG/ref=sr_1_5?crid=Q3OL5ZQERX5J&keywords=logitech%2B140%2Bheadset&qid=1698253867&sprefix=logi%2B140%2Bheadset%2Caps%2C150&sr=8-5&th=1), the audio is distorted by Linux's ALSA architecture (either something wrong with the soundcard driver or a setting inside ALSA). See [image "Problematic Recording"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVBPH.png) - the speech signal is warped in a highly unusual way. [This "Normal recording"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnCzH.png) shows what the audio recording *should* look like, but doesn't.

### Setup:

Dual-booted my computer (Rog Strix G17 RTX 3060 w/ Windows 11) with Ubuntu 22.04, upgraded to 23.04.

This problem does not occur on the exact same machine on Windows 11 running the same Python code with the same microphone. This means the problem is with how Ubuntu 23.04 is handling the audio - specifically, the problem has something to do with the ALSA architecture.

### Relevant Information:

(0) **uname -r** returns 6.2.0-35-generic

(1) **Output of aplay -l**
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
(other cards)
card 2: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC285 Analog [ALC285 Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

This last card/codec seems to be the one my system is using for digitizing my wired microphone signal.

(2) **Pavucontrol configuration**

I [attached a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3lhY.png) of my current configuration.

(3) **Output of dmesg | grep -i audio**

```bash
[    3.370747] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    3.370943] snd_hda_intel 0000:05:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    3.437596] input: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.1/sound/card1/input27
[    3.513484] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC2D0: autoconfig for ALC285: line_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    3.513493] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC2D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    3.513495] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC2D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    3.513498] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC2D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    3.513500] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC2D0:    inputs:
[    3.513501] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC2D0:      Mic=0x19
[    3.513504] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC2D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[    5.420200] input: HD-Audio Generic Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.6/sound/card2/input32
[    5.420268] input: HD-Audio Generic Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.6/sound/card2/input33
[    6.245138] snd_hda_intel 0000:05:00.1: bound 0000:05:00.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])
```

(4) **Output of pactl sources**
This is quite long:

```bash
Source #47
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor
    Description: Monitor of Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo
    Driver: PipeWire
    Sample Specification: s32le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 4294967295
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.6.analog-stereo
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        alsa.id = "ALC285 Analog"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xfc5c0000 irq 84"
        alsa.name = "ALC285 Analog"
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xfc5c0000 irq 84"
        api.alsa.card.name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        api.alsa.path = "front:2"
        api.alsa.pcm.card = "2"
        api.alsa.pcm.stream = "playback"
        audio.channels = "2"
        audio.position = "FL,FR"
        card.profile.device = "3"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "monitor"
        device.id = "42"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.routes = "2"
        factory.name = "api.alsa.pcm.sink"
        media.class = "Audio/Sink"
        device.description = "Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller"
        node.name = "alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.6.analog-stereo"
        node.nick = "ALC285 Analog"
        node.pause-on-idle = "false"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:2:front:2:playback"
        priority.driver = "1009"
        priority.session = "1009"
        factory.id = "18"
        clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
        client.id = "34"
        node.driver = "true"
        factory.mode = "merge"
        audio.adapt.follower = ""
        library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
        object.id = "47"
        object.serial = "47"
        node.max-latency = "16384/48000"
        api.alsa.period-size = "1024"
        api.alsa.period-num = "32"
        api.alsa.headroom = "0"
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "2"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio2"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:05:00.6"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
        device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_05_00.6"
        device.nick = "HD-Audio Generic"
        device.plugged.usec = "5422245"
        device.product.id = "0x15e3"
        device.product.name = "Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.6/sound/card2"
        device.vendor.id = "0x1022"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
        device.string = "2"
    Formats:
        pcm

Source #48
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_input.pci-0000_05_00.6.analog-stereo
    Description: Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo
    Driver: PipeWire
    Sample Specification: s32le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 4294967295
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 6554 /  10% / -60.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: n/a
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        alsa.id = "ALC285 Analog"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xfc5c0000 irq 84"
        alsa.name = "ALC285 Analog"
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xfc5c0000 irq 84"
        api.alsa.card.name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        api.alsa.path = "front:2"
        api.alsa.pcm.card = "2"
        api.alsa.pcm.stream = "capture"
        audio.channels = "2"
        audio.position = "FL,FR"
        card.profile.device = "0"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.id = "42"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.routes = "2"
        factory.name = "api.alsa.pcm.source"
        media.class = "Audio/Source"
        device.description = "Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller"
        node.name = "alsa_input.pci-0000_05_00.6.analog-stereo"
        node.nick = "ALC285 Analog"
        node.pause-on-idle = "false"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:2:front:2:capture"
        priority.driver = "2009"
        priority.session = "2009"
        factory.id = "18"
        clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
        client.id = "34"
        node.driver = "true"
        factory.mode = "split"
        audio.adapt.follower = ""
        library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
        object.id = "48"
        object.serial = "48"
        node.max-latency = "16384/48000"
        api.alsa.period-size = "1024"
        api.alsa.period-num = "32"
        api.alsa.headroom = "0"
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "2"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio2"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:05:00.6"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
        device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_05_00.6"
        device.nick = "HD-Audio Generic"
        device.plugged.usec = "5422245"
        device.product.id = "0x15e3"
        device.product.name = "Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.6/sound/card2"
        device.vendor.id = "0x1022"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
        device.string = "2"
    Ports:
        analog-input-internal-mic: Internal Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8900, availability group: Legacy 1, not available)
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8700, availability group: Legacy 2, available)
    Active Port: analog-input-mic
    Formats:
        pcm
```

## What I've tried

-> sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio; sudo alsa force-reload

-> I've tried changing pins with hdajackretask per various guides, but the distortion remains.

-> I updated from 22.04 LTS to 23.04.

-> I tried this (same hardware) but it didn't work: https://www.reddit.com/r/ASUSROG/comments/nvzsdw/asus_rog_g17_no_audio_speakers_are_working_in_any/

-> crying

Answer (score 0):

An extremely helpful discord user mentioned the following when I explained my setup:

"99% of the time the drivers in the kernel already are what you get, and some devices, particularly ones often found on laptops/minipc's tend to be fairly garbage hardware anyway, and may not have been implemented in a fully standard way that is supported by the generic ALC285 driver, they may be doing funky things in the windows driver and such despite using a standard chip.  I could totally be wrong, and maybe this particular card can work well with some tweaks and such.  Nonetheless, and esspecially considering this headset is pretty low end anyway, I'd just take the oppertunity to get a decent -USB- headset, or a good external USB DAC. "

I went out and purchased a Razer Blackshark V2 headset with an external USB soundcard (which was maybe overkill) and that [fixed the warping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtcjQ.png).

The amplitude is still strangely low, but that's minor.